# File and form comparison for login/session handling

Tags: php, validation, session

I would like to write to file - which is done. However, when I want to read to file and compare it to the form input via POST (for duplication and later on session handling usernames) it simply does not work. Thus I would like to either redirect the user from registration.php -> login.php -> index.php. If login via login.php and do not have an account, they will be redirected to registration.php. If there are duplicate users then return back to registration page as I have not reached that stage yet to code for error(s).

Here is my code for registration.php and the process_registration.php:

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $creditcard = $_POST["creditcard"];
    $myFile = "data.txt";

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $string = $fname . "/t";
        $array = file("data.txt");
        $duplicate = false;

        foreach ($array as $line) {
            if ( rtrim($line) == $string) {
                $duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($duplicate){
            echo 'User found';
            header("Location:error.php");
        }
        else{
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
            $comma_delimited_list = implode("\t", $_POST). "\t";
            fwrite($fh, $comma_delimited_list);
            header("Location:login.php");
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
    header("Location:login.php");
?>
```

and my register.php

```
<?php

$page_title = "Register";
include("includes/header.inc");
 ?>


<div id="content">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form method="post" action="process_register.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Credit Card</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="creditcard" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
include("includes/footer.inc");
?>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using a text file and not a database to store this information?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't have the faintest idea about how to go about incorporating a database. I'm just trying to get my head around the current code before I step into deeper waters. :(